# How to apply the same entitlement process to all of our accounts

Tags: entitlements

We are in the process of rolling out entitlements and from reading the documentation I can't see how to apply the same entitlement process to all of our accounts in one bulk action. We are planning to roll out just one entitlement process to all of our customers, however, I can only see one way of doing this by manually creating the entitlement on each account separately and choosing the entitlement process during the creation of the entitlement. As we have hundreds of accounts I need some way to be able to do this in a bulk action. Is it possible to do through dataloader, Apex code?

Thanks in advance for any help/tips on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to apply the same entitlement to all accounts.Create a dummy account, create an entitlement associated to it and add that same entitlement to every case.

Comment: Hi Kostadin, thanks for your reply. That seems to work okay. I'm just curious if this is the best way to proceed. Realistically we will only have a handful of entitlements that we need to apply to our cases, for example one for support, another for design, etc. So rather than creating a new entitlement on each of our account records individually based on the same entitlement process, is it best to just create say 3 or 4 entitlements on our fake account and have our cases linking to the specific entitlement based on different criteria? Thanks again for your help.